# How to plot a PCM wave using the binary inputs from a .txt file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pcm

In my case I will have a `PCM.txt` file which contains the binary representation of a PCM data like below.

> [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.
>   1.
>    0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.
>    0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.
>    0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
>    0. 1. 0. 1.]

**1's meaning binary 1**

**0's meaning binary 0**

This is nothing but 100 samples of data.

1. Is it possible to implement a python code which will read this `PCM.txt` as the input and plot this PCM data using matplotlib. ? Could you please give me some tips to implement this scenario ?
2. Will this plotted figure look like a square wave ?

Comment: Yes . This thing worked. I will accept your answer

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free :-)

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell . Sure

Comment: One more small question @MarkSetchell : I can even ask it in a separate thread also . I just want a yes or no answer.  Is it possible to generate a PCM from a sine wave and regenerate the same sine wave using the PCM data ?

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer than I could give if you ask a new question for that... maybe on the signal processing StackExchange site.

Comment: Sure . Thanks @MarkSetchell ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = [1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,1.]

plt.step(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you are having trouble reading the file, you can just use a regex to find things that look like numbers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import re

# Slurp entire file
with open('data') as f:
    s = f.read()

# Set y to anything that looks like a number
y = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+', s)

# Set x according to number of samples found
x = np.arange(len(y))

# Plot that thing
plt.step(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Now in the x-axis it is showing as 'no:of samples' that we have took. Instead if we want to make it in time in the x-axis what we need to do ?